# Como cambiar el FontSize de un label en tiempo de ejecucion?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy intentando cambiar el tamaño de un label en tiempo de ejecucion, he tratado con:

```
label1.Font.Size(16);
label1.Size=new Size(16);
label1.Font.SizeInPoints(16.25);
```

pero ninguna me funciona

Gracias de antemano,

Comment: en que estas trabajando? movil, escritorio o web?

Comment: escritorio, windows forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label.Size es el tamaño del componente pero no la fuente, Label.Font.Size es "`get`" para obtener el tamaño. Puedes usar esta solucion para darle tamaño.

```
Font fuente = new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, 20);
label1.Font = fuente;
```